# "speaker reliability" vs "speaker's reliability"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> 1. We should notice that **speaker reliability** is very crucial in this community.
> 2. We should notice that **speaker's reliability** is very crucial in this community.

What is the difference between the meanings of 1 and 2? And, does any of them need to have 'the'?

Answer (score -1):

Both sentences are wrong and need to be replaced with the following one. My reasons are shown below

**We should take notice that the reliability of the speaker is crucial in this community.**

**take notice** [Take notice](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/take%20notice?s) We should **admit** that the reliability of the speaker is crucial in this community.

**reliability of the speaker** when two nouns are together one becomes an adjective. An adjective is a word that describes a noun or pronoun:
When an adjective is used with a noun, the usual order in English is adjective + noun [Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/adjective-and-adverb-phrases/adjective-phrases-position)

**the** reliability; **The** is used for emphasis when you are expressing a strong opinion [Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/the)

I have **removed very** because it is used to add emphasis to an adjective or adverb to a great degree or extremely: however the use of the word **crucial means extremely important** so we are already at the level that adding very would normal elevate  the gravity of the situation too.

Comment: reliability is the quality of being able to be trusted or believed because of working or behaving well however I would be loathed to use it in this context in this sentence as reliability also means how well a machine, piece of equipment, or system works: I think that some people could confuse the two and imagine the speaker being unreliable and not turning up for their work or having a bad attitude to their work.